# Django - how to import python module?

Tags: django, sendgrid-api-v3

I would like to use [Sendgrid's python library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) so I can use their Web API for sending email from Django. I installed the library and their [example code](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/main/use_cases/django.md) says to `from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient`.  When I put this import into my app views.py, Django does not recognize this module - `import sendgrid could not be resolved`. I am running django inside docker, I did `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d --build` after pipenv install sendgrid. I then use docker-compose exec web python manage.py shell to enter the shell and I can import the module there. For some reason the import doesn't work in views though.

```
PS C:\Users\Doug\OneDrive\django\smartmark> pipenv install sendgrid
Installing sendgrid…
Adding sendgrid to Pipfile's [packages]…
Pipfile.lock (1e7343) out of date, updating to (4cf710)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Success!
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (1e7343)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (1e7343)…
  ================================ 37/37 - 00:00:02
PS C:\Users\Doug\OneDrive\django\smartmark>
```

Sendfile shows up in my Pipfile as `sendgrid = "*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install sendgrid module in your virtual environment?

Just run:

```
pip install sendgrid
```